# I can not work with linked list inside linked list

Tags: c, function, linked-list, singly-linked-list, definition

I got an idea when i started to learning linked lists. My idea was this. I want to insert 1,2,5 to a linked list. And in another field of linked list I want to add 2 digit numbers that starts with 1,2,5. You can see from image. ( C means combinations )
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1QMj.jpg

```
int main() {
struct Node* head = NULL;
insertEnd(&head,1);
insertEnd(&head,2);
insertEnd(&head,5);
printLinkedList(head);
insertStartsWith(&head,5,51);
insertStartsWith(&head,5,52);
insertStartsWith(&head,5,53);
insertStartsWith(&head,5,54);
insertStartsWith(&head,1,11);
insertStartsWith(&head,1,12);
insertStartsWith(&head,1,13);
insertStartsWith(&head,1,14);
insertStartsWith(&head,2,21);
insertStartsWith(&head,2,22);
insertStartsWith(&head,2,23);
insertStartsWith(&head,2,24);
printLinkedListWithStartsWith(head);}
```

My node structure:

```
struct Node {
int data;
struct Node* next;
struct Node* startsWith; };
```

My code for inserting initial linked list 1,2 and 5:

```
void insertEnd(struct Node **pNode, int data){
struct Node* newNode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
struct Node *lastNode=*pNode;
newNode->data=data;
newNode->next=NULL;
if (*pNode==NULL)
{
    *pNode=newNode;
    return;
}
while (lastNode->next!=NULL){
    lastNode=lastNode->next;
}
lastNode->next=newNode;
return; }
```

This part is search number and insert 2 digit numbers to it's startsWith node.

```
void insertStartsWith(struct Node **pNode, int i, int i1) {
struct Node *tempNode=*pNode;
while (tempNode->next!=NULL){
    if (tempNode->data==i){
        struct Node *tempNode1=tempNode->startsWith;
        while (tempNode1->next!=NULL){
            tempNode1=tempNode1->next;
        }
        struct Node* newNode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->data=i1;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        tempNode1->next=newNode;
        return;
    }
    tempNode=tempNode->next;
} }
```

I add 1 2 and 5 to my linked list. But when I try to add combinations it fails. Where should I look for linked list inside a linked list?

edit 08.18.19

```
void printLinkedListWithStartsWith(struct Node *pNode) {
printf("Linked list with starts: ");
while (pNode!=NULL) {
    printf("%d \n",pNode->data);
    while(pNode->startsWith!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",pNode->startsWith->data);
        pNode->startsWith=pNode->startsWith->next;
    }
    pNode=pNode->next;
} }
```

Comment: You never initialize `startsWidth`. This means `while (tempNode1->next!=NULL)` dereferences an uninitialized pointer. If you initialize correctly to `NULL` here you would need to check for `NULL` before dereferencing.

Comment: "It fails" is not a useful description. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and tell us what you expect and what you got instead. How did you check? Did you check values in debuffer of only check output of `printLinkedListWithStartsWith` which you didn't chow us BTW.

Comment: Oh, and you could improve the readability of your code drastically by applying some proper indentation.

Comment: Thou shalt not cast the return value of `malloc()` in C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two structs in each other for linked list of linked lists makes it clear:

```c
typedef struct List List;
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node{
    size_t size;
    int value;
    Node* node;
    List *list_value;

};

struct List{
    size_t size;
    Node* node;
};
```

And you can write functions to insert data into lists:

```c
//Inserts list into listP
void list_set_list_value(List* listP, size_t index, List * list_valueP){
        (*listP).node[index].list_value=list_valueP;
}

//Inserts value into listP
void list_set_int_value(List* listP, size_t index, int valueP){
        (*listP).node[index].value=valueP;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `insertEnd` you have to initialize all data members of the structure `Node`.

Function `insertStartsWith` has undefined behavior. The expression `*pNode` can be equal to `NULL`. So in this statement

```
while (tempNode->next!=NULL){
```

there is an attempt to access memory using a null-pointer.

Moreover this while loop

```
while (tempNode->next!=NULL)
```

does not make sense because for the first node `tempNode->next` can be equal to `NULL` but the function does nothing in this case. It just exits the loop an returns the control to the calling function.

What you need to do is to find a node with the value `i` and if such a node is found then call the function `insertEnd` passing pointer to the data member `startsWith` of the found node and the value of the variable `ii`.

The function can look the following way.

```
int insertStartsWith(struct Node **pNode, int i, int i1) 
{
    while ( *pNode != NULL && ( *pNode )->data != i ) pNode = &( *pNode )->next;

    int success = *pNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        insertEnd( &( *pNode )->startsWith, ii );
    }

    return success;
}
```

If a node with the value of the variable `i` is not found then an alternative approach is to create such a node. For example

```
void insertStartsWith(struct Node **pNode, int i, int i1) 
{
    while ( *pNode != NULL && ( *pNode )->data != i ) pNode = &( *pNode )->next;

    if ( *pNode == NULL )
    {
         *pNode = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
         ( *pNode )->data = i;
         ( *pNode )->next = NULL;
         ( *pNode )->startsWith = NULL;
    }

    insertEnd( &( *pNode )->startsWith, ii );
}
```